# How to select rows based on above rows | Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, rows

```
0| name1 | name2 | tot |
 +-------+-------+-----+
1|   A   |   B   |  3  |
2|   C   |   A   |  3  |
3|   B   |   D   |  4  |
4|   A   |   E   |  2  |
5|   B   |   C   |  5  |
 +-------+-------+-----+
```

I want to select rows based on the previuous rows, where a "letter" is present in other rows above at least 2 time (respectively in name1 or name2) and their tot is >= 3.

In this example i want to select:

```
A    E   2
B    C   5
```

because in 4th row we have A (name1) that appear in 1st and 2nd rows, with a tot >= 3;
and the B C 5 rows, because we have B that appear in 1st and 3rd rows, with a tot >= 3.

ps. I want to create another dataset based on these new results

Answer (score 0):

You can build a cache using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'name1': list('ACBAB'), 'name2': list('BADEC'), 'tot': [3, 3, 4, 2, 5]})

seen = defaultdict(int) # every new key will be initialized with 0
keep = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    keep.append(
        (seen[row.name1] > 1) |
        (seen[row.name2] > 1)
    )
    if row.tot >= 3:
        # we can do this safely without risk of KeyError because `seen` is a default dict
        seen[row.name1] += 1 
        seen[row.name2] += 1

out = df[keep]
```

Output

```
  name1 name2  tot
3     A     E    2
4     B     C    5
```